# How to add placeholder in wp_editor?

Tags: tinymce, editor, wp-editor

i would like to add placeholder when using `wp_editor()` function.

I tried to pass placeholder attribute in textarea, but didn't work. I tried to pass it in settings

```
 wp_editor( 
     $project_description , 
     'project_description', 
     array(
         'wpautop'       => true,
         'media_buttons' => false,
         'textarea_name' => 'project_description',
         'editor_class'  => 'is-project-description-textarea',
         'textarea_rows' => 5,
         //'textarea_placeholder' => 'Project Description WP Editor Default',
         'placeholder' => 'Project Description WP Editor Default 2'
     ) 
 );
```

I checked then the [_WP_Editors::parse_settings( string $editor_id, array $settings ): array](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/_WP_Editors/parse_settings/)

Also tried to replace `<textarea` with `<textarea placeholder="`

```
 $wpEditorPlaceholder = 'My Placeholder';
 $wpEditor = wp_editor( 
     $project_description , 
     'project_description', 
     array(
         'wpautop'       => true,
         'media_buttons' => false,
         'textarea_name' => 'project_description',
         'editor_class'  => 'is-project-description-textarea',
         'textarea_rows' => 5,
     ) 
 );
 $wpEditorNew = str_replace('<textarea', '<textarea placeholder="' . $wpEditorPlaceholder . '" ', $wpEditor);
 echo $wpEditorNew;
```

but didn't work and then i added it via `add_action`

```
add_action('the_editor', 'add_placeholder_to_editor');
function add_placeholder_to_editor($editorMarkup)
{
    if (str_contains($editorMarkup, 'is-project-description-textarea')) { 
        $editorMarkup = str_replace('<textarea', '<textarea placeholder="Hello"', $editorMarkup);
    }
    return $editorMarkup;
}
```

Placeholder added successfully but it didn't show it when js loaded

[image]  [image]

Then i thought to add tinymce in settings

```
wp_editor( 
     $project_description , 
     'project_description', 
     array(
         'wpautop'       => true,
         'media_buttons' => false,
         'textarea_name' => 'project_description',
         'editor_class'  => 'is-project-description-textarea',
         'textarea_rows' => 5,
         'tinymce'   => array(
            'paste_as_text' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'Project Description',
         )
     ) 
 );
```

Key `paste_as_text` worked but key `placeholder` didn't work.

What i miss? How can i add placeholder attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to replace `<textarea` with `<textarea placeholder="` is correct. Just `wp_editor` function does not returns html code, which you can change. Function just echoes output.

You can capture this output with `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171327/2234089):

```php
  $wpEditorPlaceholder = 'My Placeholder';
  ob_start();
  wp_editor( 
     $project_description , 
     'project_description', 
     array(
         'wpautop'       => true,
         'media_buttons' => false,
         'textarea_name' => 'project_description',
         'editor_class'  => 'is-project-description-textarea',
         'textarea_rows' => 5,
     ) 
  );
  $wpEditor = ob_get_clean();
  $wpEditorNew = str_replace('<textarea', '<textarea placeholder="' . 
  $wpEditorPlaceholder . '" ', $wpEditor);
  echo $wpEditorNew;
```

Or, even, you can add placeholder with the action. Unfortunately, there's no TinyMCE setting for adding placeholder, but you can use two filters to add placeholder: `wp_editor_settings` - to remember placeholder value and `the_editor` - to alter `<textarea>` tag.

Example code for your `functions.php`, or for your plugin:

```php
class AddPlaceholderTinyMCE {
    private $placeholder = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', array( $this, 'wp_editor_settings_callback' ), 10, 2 );
    }

    public function wp_editor_settings_callback( $settings, $editor_id ) {
        if ( ! empty( $settings['tinymce']['placeholder'] ) ) {
            $this->placeholder = $settings['tinymce']['placeholder'];
            add_filter( 'the_editor', array( $this, 'the_editor_callback' ) );
        }
    }

    public function the_editor_callback( $html ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_editor', array( $this, 'the_editor_callback' ) );
        return str_replace( '<textarea', '<textarea placeholder="' . esc_attr( $this->placeholder ) . '"', $html );
    }
}

new AddPlaceholderTinyMCE();
```

When you call `wp_editor` with `placeholder` setting for tinymce, it will show you specified placeholder value:

```php
wp_editor( 
     $project_description , 
     'project_description', 
     array(
         ...
         'tinymce'   => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Project Description',
         )
     ) 
 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both of your suggestions are working in text editor but visual editor shows empty. Everything is updated to latest version and there aren't any errors in console. Also i deactivated all plugins with same results.
text editor with ob_get_clean (https://ibb.co/wwQZ459), text editor with filters (https://ibb.co/6NCB4sn) and visual editor (https://ibb.co/4jZ2gCs)

Comment: Seems that WordPress using older version of TinyMCE, that does not have built in feature to display placeholder over visual text editor. [Newer version](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-placeholder-text/) have it. I was thinking about updating TinyMCE to that new version, but It probably will be incompatible with WordPress. It will be easier to write a plugin for current TinyMCE version, that will just show that placeholder in visual editor. Easier, but not easy.